# Stackdriver webhook token authentication and best practices

Tags: google-cloud-platform, webhooks, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am planning to receive GCP stackdriver alerting via webhooks to an on-premise network. I need some recommendation on how to manage privacy and authentication. I will be using an SSL enabled endpoint URL and I am trying to find documentation to set up token authentication or even possibilities to white list IP addresses/domain on my on-premise firewall.

Comment: Here is an article that I wrote on how to get the Stackdriver IP addresses for whitelisting: https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-stackdriver-ip-addresses/ I am not sure what you are referring to for token authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Stackdriver can use basic authentication (so you definitely want to use SSL/TLS). In the ui, check the checkbox for basic auth and enter a username and password. I recommend choosing a strong, high-entropy password.  You can read more on basic authentication [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication), but the basic idea is that your endpoint will receive a request with a header that looks like this:

```
Authentication: Basic <Base64 Value>
```

Simply pull the `Authentication` header value, strip off `Basic` (including the space) from the beginning and base64 decode the rest. The base64 decoded value should just be `username:password`. Check that that matches what you have stored and you should be good to go.

Additionally, you can get the list of Google Uptime IP addresses [here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/uptime-checks/using-uptime-checks#get-ips) and check that the IP address the request came from matches those. I'd recommend this only as a second factor to the basic auth as any change on Google's side could result in either rejection of legitimate traffic or allowance of non-legitimate traffic on your side.